# Hover эффект блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно реализовать данный hover эффект ?

Comment: добавьте :after и с position: absolute сдвиньте его влево, за границу вашего основного блока.
Задайте border-radius: 50% и размер, чтоб он не попадал в видимость основного блока. У основного блока задайте overflow: hide. При наведении на основной блок, просто увеличивайте элемент :after при помощи scale(3) (нужное значение подберите). А цвет текста, думаю знаете как поменять

Comment: @Evgenii я понимаю как сделать сделать это через border и с scale. Главная проблема. как сделать такую фигуру, чтобы она плавно изменялась

Comment: ниже дал ответ, оно?

Comment: @Evgenii там просто круг, который слева снизу появляется, а видео фигура, которая меняет свою форму

Comment: как в этом генераторе?
https://9elements.github.io/fancy-border-radius/#30.78.87.17--424.461
Такое задается при помощи border-radius. Можно поиграться и найти что-то похожее

Comment: @Evgenii в качестве ответа укажите это сообщение, да это то

Comment: Обычно для этого раскадровку скидывают. И почему-то мне кажется, что там нужно использовать SVG, морфить его и всё такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил border-rdius + rotate для более эффектного появления:

```css
.main {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden
}

.main h1 {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .6s;
}

.main:hover h1 {
  color: yellow;
}

.main:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 70%;
  left: -50px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 11% 89% 80% 20% / 60% 14% 86% 40%;
  transition: all .6s;
}

.main:hover:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(7) rotate(145deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Просто текст</h1>
</div>
```